# Why haven't I got a notification that an answer has been posted to my question?

Tags: bug

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1449127/how-to-set-refresh-rate-60hz-on-the-tv-when-connected-to-hdmi) today. An answer was posted after an hour, but I haven't got any notifications for it.

[image]

Any updates on this?

Comment: Did you select the option when you submitted the question originally?

Comment: @Ramhound That option is for email notifications.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - You have to select the checkbox, no?

Comment: Yes, but this question is about website notifications, not email notifications. The screenshot shows there was no notification to show he had a new answer on his question.

Comment: @Ramhound I got a notification for the comment here, and also the comment on the answer posted on my question, but still no notification for the answer itself